# How to show a spinning wheel loader in VF page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I want to make my VF page open with a spinning wheel loader, once the loading is done it should render all the components present in that page.
PS:I have embedded Lightning components in my VF page. The current scenario is URL and spinner is not in  a sync.

```
<style>
                .uiSpinner+div{ visibility: hidden; }                 
                .loading{ width:100% !important; height:100% important; display:block;  margin:20% auto; border:0; fadeOut:2000; }               
                .spinner-img{ margin:0 auto; color:red; width:5%; height:5%;}
                .dottedUnderLine{border-bottom : #ccc 1px dotted;}              
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript" >
 //Integrating Tab lightnign component. 

    $(document).ready( function() {
    $Lightning.use("c:TabPanelcmptApp", function() 
    {

       $Lightning.createComponent("c:TabPanelcmpt", {"campId":'{!campId}'},  "lightning");
    });

     $(window).load(function(){
                $(".uiSpinner").css("display","none");                    
                $(".uiSpinner+div").css("visibility","visible");
                <!--$(".uiSpinner").delay(1500).fadeOut("500");-->
            });

 <!-- Loading gif component -->               

                <div class="spinner uiSpinner" role="alert"  >
                    <div class="loading">
                        <span class="uiImage" >
                            <img src="/auraFW/resources/aura/images/spinner.gif" class="spinner-img"  alt="Loading" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div> 

<!-- End of loading gif component -->
```

When my VF page is getting loaded I want that spinner also to be loaded till all my components get rendered in that page. But the spinner stops loading, and the components is getting rendered only when the Page is loaded fully.

Comment: What do you mean by "URL and spinner is not in a sync"?

Comment: Thanks for replying. When my VF page is getting loaded i want that spinner also to be loaded till all my components get rendered in that page. But the spinner stops loading, and the components is getting rendered only when the Page is loaded fully. I hope you understood.

Comment: @ArshadHabee What about the case where your spinner.gif has not yet loaded?